# Jquery post to Spring controller to return java bean for jstl parsing

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, spring

I'm new to jquery and SpringMVC.  I'm using jquery to submit a request after a user clicks a href.  After the server processes the request, a modal popup is displayed with the details from the server.

```
$.post(taskSrchURL, function(data) {
  $('#popupmodal').modal('show');
});
```

Here is the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/task/{id}", method =    
{RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView searchDetails(@PathVariable("id") String 
id,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws SearchException, ApplicationException {

Details details = service.getDetails(id, request, response);

prepareResponse(request, response, taskDetails);
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("details ");
modelAndView.addObject("details ", details);
return modelAndView;
```

I'm expecting to have access to the "details" object when the response returns, however, I'm not sure how to access it.  I'm expecting to be able to use jstl tags to reference the data as it is complex and needs to be dispalyed on several tabs.

However,

```
<c:out value="${details.id}"/>
```

does not work.  I have seen a lot examples that set the 'data' from the ModalAndView to the html element of a div, but I don't want to do that.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like you have an additional space the word "details" of `new ModelAndView("details ")` and `modelAndView.addObject("details ", details)`?

Comment: Thanks for your response @echen.  The space after "details" is just a typo when transferring the code to stackoverflow. Removing it doesn't make a difference.  So my question is, after adding the "details" to the ModelAndView object, should I be able to access the java bean using jstl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have 2 choices:

**Client-side rendering:**

If the data you need from the server can be inserted into your page with javascript without too much hassle, you should return it as JSON from your Controller method using `@ResponseBody`. Convertion to JSON can be done by Jackson automatically.

You could then use an existing Javascript template engine library to render your data to html on the clients browser and insert it into the page or just insert it manually (for example with jQuery).

---

**Server-side rendering:**

If you want to render the part of the page with the data on the server-side to then send the ready-made part of your page back to the client, you need a template engine which allows you to render your templates anytime anywhere (in your controller method in this case). You could then send the html String back again as JSON using `@ResponseBody` and insert it into the page.

I don't think JSP/JSTL can do this (or it is very difficult/hacky). I  recommend [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) instead.

You could still use JSP/JSTL for your "complete" pages, and FreeMarker for the parts. FreeMarker is not too different from JSP/JSTL, so you could probably translate the part of your page without too much problems.

Comment: Thank you Katharsas, I used @ResponseBody and its now working.

Answer (score 0):

Besides my comment, I would highly recommend using the `@ResponseBody` annotation instead of using `ModelAndView`

Be sure to have `jackson-databind` on your classpath, this will cause Spring to automatically serialize your POJO into JSON, which can be directly used as Javascript objects in the ajax callback function

See a quick tutorial here:
http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program

This approach decouples the Application Server from your view, thus liberating you from having to rely on JSTL templating and you can choose a front-end workflow that is intuitive for you (checkout AngularJS).

Comment: Thank you echen, I used @ResponseBody and it is now working. Thanks for your response.